# is there a service to create and upload crash dumps for mac and win apps?

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio-2010, debugging, remote-debugging

I have a cross platform desktop C++ app for Mac OSX and Windows, for which I'd like to collect debug info when a crash happens on a user's computer, so I can find out what the problem is and fix my code. On Windows I'm using visual studio express 2010 and on Mac I'm using Xcode 3 as IDE. I remember an online service where you could sign up and link your code with a library, so the app would upload crash info to the service, which you could then use to fix the app, but I can't find it anymore after googling for 10 minutes. Can anyone help?

Thanks!
B

Comment: On Windows, you don't need a library. WinQual will collect crashes anyway. ("Send error report to Microsoft"). If your executable is signed, so you can prove to Microsoft it's yours, then you can access that collected crash data. Microsoft will even categorize the crashes for you.

Comment: i need a solution for mac osx too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/) for the google-breakpad project. I think this is what you need. I was going to use it for a project so I researched about it but then the project ended so I didn't have a chance to. You link your program with it and when the program crashes, it generates a crash dump that is not compatible with any of the platform-specific crash dump formats but has its own one. You can then analyse them with a program that is part of the breakpad project. As far as I remember, there is also a service that you can install, where the crash dumps can be uploaded. The service then can analyse and group them by reason etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like something I could use. I'll have to look more into it because it's not clear immediately if breakpad just has to be added to the app itself or if it also has to be in every library I'm using in the project (some of which are open source and some of which are closed source).

Comment: I also remember there being some commercial projects which offered support, etc.